# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null init

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to put some xml data (productType.xml) into an html file (customo.php) I have using javascript (script.js) for users to select a category of products.

**script.js**

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
var xml;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xml.open("GET","data/productType.xml",false);
xml.send();
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
var message;
for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    message = "<div class='pro'><p>" + x.getElementsByTagName("category")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"</p><img src='"+ x.getElementsByTagName("catimage")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "' alt='Picture' /></div>"; 
}
document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML = message;
}
```

**productType.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<products>
<product>
    <category>Pens</category>
    <catimage>d-u-b/ball1.png</catimage>
    <types>
        <one>Laser</one>
        <two>Plain</two>
    </types>
    <colors>
        <one>Pink</one>
        <two>Red</two>
        <three>Blue</three>
        <four>Black</four>
    </colors>
    <price>2.99</price>
</product>
<product>
    <category>Stress Balls</category>
    <catimage>d-u-b/ball1.png</catimage>
    <types>
        <one>Round</one>
        <two>Custom</two>
    </types>
    <images>
        <one>d-u-b/ball1.png</one>
        <two>d-u-b/custom.png</two>
    </images>
    <colors>
        <one>Green</one>
        <two>Red</two>
        <three>Blue</three>
        <four>Light Blue</four>
    </colors>
    <imagecolors>
        <one>d-u-b/ballgreen.png</one>
        <two>d-u-b/ballred.png</two>
        <three>d-u-b/ballblue.png</three>
        <four>d-u-b/balllightblue.png</four>
    </imagecolors>
    <price>1.99</price>
</product>
</products>
```

I am having this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null init" script.js 14

Line 14

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
```

I have tried debugging and it gets through the xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

Can anyone see whats going on?